# Getting weird values on predicting MNIST dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, mnist, tflearn

I am using TF.LEARN with mnist data. I trained my neural network with 0.96 accuracy but now I am not really sure how to predict a value.

Here is my code..

```
#getting mnist data to a zip in the computer.
mnist.SOURCE_URL = 'https://web.archive.org/web/20160117040036/http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/'
trainX, trainY, testX, testY = mnist.load_data(one_hot=True)


# Define the neural network
def build_model():
    # This resets all parameters and variables
    tf.reset_default_graph()
    net = tflearn.input_data([None, 784])
    net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 100, activation='ReLU')
    net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 10, activation='softmax') 
    net = tflearn.regression(net, optimizer='sgd', learning_rate=0.1, loss='categorical_crossentropy')
    # This model assumes that your network is named "net"    
    model = tflearn.DNN(net)
    return model

# Build the model
model = build_model()

model.fit(trainX, trainY, validation_set=0.1, show_metric=True, batch_size=100, n_epoch=8)

#Here is the problem 
#lets say I want to predict what my neural network will reply back if I put back the send value from my trainX
```

`the value of trainX[2] is 4`

```
pred = model.predict([trainX[2]])
print(pred)
#What I get is 
[[2.6109733880730346e-05, 4.549271125142695e-06, 1.8098366126650944e-05, 0.003199575003236532, 0.20630565285682678, 0.0003870908112730831, 4.902480941382237e-05, 0.006617342587560415, 0.018498118966817856, 0.764894425868988]]
```

## what I want is -> 4

The problem is that I am not sure how to use this predict function and put in the trainX value to get a prediction.

Answer (score 0):

The prediction of tensorflow gives you a probabilistic output. It is sufficient to get the label with maximum probability from `pred` to get the peediction of the network.

```
pred = np.argmax(pred, axis=1)
```

Which in this case is not 4, but 9.

Where `np` is numpy module imported as `import numpy as np`, but feel free to replace it with `tf.argmax(pred, 1)` to use tensorflow's argmax instead.

Comment: I got the answer by doing this 
pred = model.predict([trainX[5]])
print(np.argmax(pred))
But thanks for telling me about tf.argmax(pred,1)

Comment: I think i wasnt clear with my question, I just wanted to know how to calculate the index number, which is basically by using np.argmax ... Sorry for the confusion. I really appreciate the answer!

Comment: @MasnadNihit if you have only 1 prediction then `np.argmax` works for you. If you have more than one, then you need `np.argmax(pred, 1)` to get all the indexes for all the predictions simultaneously.

Comment: Yes I had one prediction, sorry but thanks for the help! I learned a bit more.
I will keep this question here so if it might help someone in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a 9, which is quite similar to a 4.

What `model.predict` returns is **score** and while the 5-th value in the results array (the 5th value is 4 since it starts with a zero) gets a relatively high score (0.26-second high) - your model gives the last digit (9) the highest score-0.76. It just means your classifier is a bit wrong here - so you should consider using a different one or play with the hyper-parameters.

Comment: Thanks benieve! I figured out what the problem was. Here is the final solution to my problem
pred = model.predict([trainX[5]])
print(np.argmax(pred))

Comment: @benieve, I think i wasnt clear with my question, I just wanted to know how to calculate the index number, which is basically by using np.argmax ... Sorry for the confusion. I really appreciate the answer!